# VSCode not autocompleting all Django modules' functions

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, python-venv

It looks like autocompleting is not working for all the functions for some Django modules? For example, I am importing
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

but when trying to create a new user:

`user = User.objects.create_user(etc)` is not showing the create_user function. [image]

Also, if I type in a name of non-existing function VSCode will show an error, example below:

[image]

Any thoughts please?

FYI: I am running VSCode on Ubuntu and django is installed in a venv. Interpreter is set to **.../venv/bin/python3.10**

Comment: I am always setting my Python Interpreter to my virtual env. so it can get all the modules installed from pip, maybe try that?

Comment: Whats wrong with above? It is showing autocompletion suggestions

Comment: @MohitC not showing all functions, create_(user|superuser) for example are missing

Comment: @A.P. can you please talk me through it incase I am doing something incorrectly?

Comment: sure, ctr+shift+p > search for `Python: select interpreter` -> click on that and look for your virtual env,  it should be something like that: `~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/envs/<virtual_env_name>/bin/python` where 3.10.2 is your python version. Also, you can try typing `create_` and see if the autocomplete that you looking for comes out.

Comment: @A.P. yeah this is what I am doing, except that inside each django project I create the venv. for example inside ~/projects/first, I run `python -m venv .venv`. Still no luck, not all functions/attributes are showing.

Comment: What plugins/extensions you have installed on VSCode and do you have any formatting provider such as pep? Also, there is a language mode selection in the bottom right corner, is it python?

Comment: @A.P. https://imgur.com/a/LyLuoS7

Comment: Haven't used it but you can try `Djaneiro - Django Snippets` other than that I am not sure how to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245098/discussion-between-0xab3d-and-a-p).